# 1rem not always equal to 16px

Tags: html, css, font-size

Lets say I have the following HTML:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

And the following CSS:

```
h1{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

The default size for 1rem in my browser (chrome) is 16px, but whilst inspecting the element, I noticed that the height of the h1 was actually 18px, not 16px, so is something wrong here, or is this intentded, and how do I set it to 16px?

Comment: You're going to have to demo that....font-size does not equal height...but **line-height** *might*.

Comment: There are other things that can affect the height that is being taken up by the element in the browser display.  Line-height is likely your issue, but it could be other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting `16px` as font size it doesn't mean the actual character will be 16px.

It means the total height of the text will be 16 pixel, big letters, small letter, letter like "j" sit lower than for example "n" and "f" sits higher.

[image]

Src: https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/